# multiple file uploads using webforms in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal. I am using Drupal 7. I have few forms in my system that uses Webform module. I need to a functionality through which I can upload multiple file using the form.

Is there a way to do this?

I used https://drupal.org/project/webform_multifile, but for some reason I am not gettinf new control in edit webform page.

I also tried https://drupal.org/project/webform_multiple_file but it need webforms 4.x.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try out the [Plupload](https://drupal.org/project/plupload) module.

Hope that helps.